# Conditional Disable / Re-Enable jQuery click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I've got a problem with disabling and re-enabling click events on links.

The setup is 4 columns in a row, each column containing a link and hidden content box. When you click a link, it expands the row and displays content box specific to that column. Once a link is clicked and the row expanded, all of the other links are then faded out. You would then re-click the open link to close the row and un-fade the other links.

I've setup a working fiddle of this scenario which should help explain it...

http://jsfiddle.net/r8K78/2/

```
$('.open-box').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $list_row = $(this).parents('.row'),
        $column_box = $(this).parent('.column').find('.box');

    if ( $(this).is('.open') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $list_row.stop().animate({ 'padding-bottom': 0 }, 100).removeClass('expanded');
        // hide the content box
        $column_box.hide();
        // find all links and fade them in
        $('.box-list').find('.box-link').fadeTo(100, 1).addClass('open-box');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $list_row.stop().animate({ 'padding-bottom': 200 }, 100, function() {
            // show the content box
            $column_box.fadeIn(100);
        }).addClass('expanded');
        // find all links and fade them out
        $('.box-list').find('.box-link').not(this).fadeTo(100, 0.25).removeClass('open-box');
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is disable the click event on all the faded out links, leaving the open link as the only click-able link. As you can see, the behavior of clicking a faded out link makes the whole thing go batty.

I've tried setting `.off('click')` on the open action (else) which does the job of disabling the click on the other links. And put `.on('click')` on the close action. After the close action runs, the other links are still not clickable.

Any help on figuring this out would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: you could just check for opacity: `if ($(this).css('opacity') < 1) return;` http://jsfiddle.net/r8K78/4/

Comment: Brilliant and so simple! Want to put it in as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check for opacity:

```
if ($(this).css('opacity') < 1) return;
```

[SEE](http://jsfiddle.net/r8K78/4/)

But better would be to set a class on faded out elements and check for this class instead, making code more readable/maintanable.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8K78/5/)

Comment: I like that approach too. Good stuff! Really appreciate the help!